# How to call gnuplot from CLI and save the output graph to the image file?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm writing a batch file which will also generate a gnuplot graph from a dat file.

I wish to call gnuplot from the command line, using the gnuplot "gnu" script I have written, and save the output graph to an image.

Something like:

```
gnuplot.exe script.gnu > image.png
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply putting the following line will make gnuplot to return png-format bytecode. Thus, you can redirect the output to a png-file.

```
set terminal png
```

Comment: or, if you have cairo enabled terminals and you want to make a nicer looking plot:  `set terminal pngcairo` :)

Answer (score 11):

You don't have to redirect the output from gnuplot into an image file; you can set that inside the gnuplot script itself:

```
set terminal png
set output 'image.png'
```

If you want to have a variable output name, one simple way to do that in bash is to wrap the gnuplot commands thus:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "set terminal png
set output '$1'
plot 'data.dat'" | gnuplot
```

This way you can run the bash script with an argument for the output file name:

```
./plotscript.sh image.png
```

Comment: Rather than using `echo` with a pipe, you could always use a [HERE document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 2):

When your batch file runs gnuplot only (with the script) and does nothing else,
then you can combine the batch file with the gnuplot script:

```
@echo off & call gnuplot -e "echo='#';set macros" "%~f0" & goto :eof

set terminal png
set output 'image.png'
...
```

Save this with **.cmd** extension.
The advantages of this is that:

- you have only 1 file instead of two
- that file is runnable from Explorer/TaskScheduler/etc. in a portable way
  (no need to associate a new extension with gnuplot.exe)

In other words, this is the Windows "equivalent"(?) of the `#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot` solution of Unix
(this is why I find it so comfortable when working with gnuplot scripts under Windows).
(Note: 'call gnuplot' is used to allow for a gnuplot.cmd file somewhere in the PATH -- as opposed to polluting the PATH with the folder of gnuplot.exe (and many other programs).)

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions doesn't work, you need to implement:

First: create the script.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/sh  
gnuplot << EOF  
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced  
set output "$1.eps" # all the declarations that you need  
set xlabel "Energy [MeV]"  
plot "$1.dat" using 1:2 notitle w l  
EOF
```

Second: execute the script:

```
$ ./script.sh data
```

The parameter data is the .dat file that you will use for to graph...

It really works!