# How to use gnuplot with Batch?

Tags: batch-file, gnuplot

I just started using gnuplot and I wonder how I can use gnuplot with batch.
I have a Script that counts every line and every commentline in a .bat file and saves the result in a csv and dat file. That works fine.
Here is how I save my results.

```
REM ---------------SAVE_RESULTS------------------------START----------------
ECHO Programm;total lines;comment lines> ./Result/%CSV_NAME%
ECHO %Script_Name%;%ALL_Counter%;%REM_Counter% >> ./Result/%CSV_NAME%
ECHO 0 total-lines       %ALL_Counter%> ./TEMP_DAT/%DAT_NAME%
ECHO 1 comment-lines       %REM_Counter% >> ./TEMP_DAT/%DAT_NAME%
REM ---------------SAVE_RESULTS------------------------END------------------
```

This is a example .dat file

```
0 total-lines        14
1 comment-lines        7
```

Now I tried to call gnuplot in Batch but it doenst realy work that way and I have no idea how it works or if it can even work that way.

```
REM ---------------PLOTTING_CHART------------------------START--------------
C:\Temp\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot './TEMP_DAT/%DAT_NAME%' using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes

REM ---------------PLOTTING_CHART------------------------END----------------
```

I want to make a bar chart and save it as a png

Can someone explain me how I can properly use gnuplot with batch?

Comment: I find your question very hard to understand! What has `gnuplot` got to do with counting lines? Maybe you are looking for this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18890512/2836621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
REM ---------------PLOTTING_CHART------------------------START--------------
REM create .plt
ECHO set term png>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set yrange [0:%ALL_COUNTER%] >>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set terminal png size 1024,768>>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set terminal pngcairo font "arial,10" size 500,500>>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set output "SCP_V1_test.png">>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set boxwidth 0.75>>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set style fill solid>>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO set title "SCP Tested File:%Script_Name%">>./%PLT_NAME%
ECHO plot '%SOURCE_PATH%TEMP_DAT\%DAT_NAME%' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes>>./%PLT_NAME%


C:\Temp\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot.exe -p -e load'./%PLT_NAME%'


REM ---------------PLOTTING_CHART------------------------END----------------
```

I just create a gnuplot script within my batch script and start it.